# Selecting columns whose name matches a regular expression in PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql

How can I select only those *columns* whose name matches a regular expression in PostgreSQL?

For example, how do I select only the columns whose name begins with 'A' in the following table, without explicitly enumerating them in the select list?

```
id  A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 B
1   a  b  c  d  e  f
2   g  h  i  j  k  l
```

Comment: Short answer: you can't. You could do this with dynamic SQL and a function if you really need to do this. But these kind of "requirements" often hide a different problem, such as a wrong data model. Numbered columns where the name means something do raise a red flag.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: You're right: I would have designed the schema differently. But given the schema this would be very useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to write a dynamic `sql('select '||colname||' from (yourtable)')` to accomplish this and dynamic sql should have supplied column names from the following sql:

```sql
SELECT column_name 
    FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_name = '<your table>' 
    AND column_name LIKE '<beginning of column name>%';
```